# Unable to get MAMP working at all

Tags: osx-lion, wordpress, mamp

I've installed MAMP on my imac 27 running `os x 10.7.2`. I have read dozens of articles on configuration and tried every possible combination that I can think of but, am either getting a `404 Page not found` or `Firefox is unable to connect to the server at localhost`. I'm using `wordpress 3.3.1`.

In `Preferences - Apache`:

- I have used the select button to the wordpress folder so that should
  be correct.
- I have tried `http://localhost/wordpress` and
  `localhost:8888/wordpress` and both with `/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress` so I don't think it is a question of paths.
- I've changed the ports to no avail.
- I've put the database name and passwords in the `wp_config.php`
  folder according to instructions
- I've also tried opening it as
  `wp-config-sample.php` which should automatically open a configuration
  panel in wordpress.

Any other ideas out there?

Comment: I never had good luck with MAMP and, frankly, I don't trust a company trying to charge for the work of others who give it away for free. Try XAMPP for Mac. It's the original and I've had good luck with it in windows and OS X. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll try it because I'm not getting anywhere with MAMP. Hopefully it works in Lion.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it in lion.

Comment: Thanks skub - 10 mins work and I'm up and running on XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

May want to checkout [DesktopServer Limited](http://serverpress.com/products/desktopserver/#compare). It is XAMPP but optimized for WordPress. It does what MAMP Pro does for FREE and even includes the latest version of WordPress. Also, you can copy your complete site, settings, plugins, themes, etc.. Great way to template and jump start your projects.